# Threes "Special Thanks" secret message

Tags: threes

In the game *Threes* (on Android), there is a "Special Thanks" section with a swipe to see more message at the bottom.

There's a potential cryptic message "somewhat hidden there.

[image]

Does anyone know if it means something?

Comment: Looks like there's [some speculation](https://m.reddit.com/r/iosgaming/comments/1xc4zm/theres_some_kind_of_secret_code_in_the_options/), but no definitive answers. The theory that the pictograms represent the unique Threes block "characters" seems plausible, given that many of the pictograms resemble a facial feature of one of the blocks.